# add an extra attribute to an ORM model to indicate the source table for that item

Tags: sqlalchemy

I believe I looked everywhere but I cannot find an easy way to do this in SQLAlchemy. I'd like to add a 'dummy' column in my return

```
SELECT *,"MINI" AS source FROM INV1 WHERE ITEMID = 'test1'
```

I need this as I use a union of 3 different tables, and I need to know from what table the result is

My 'ultimate' query that I'd like to convert to ORM is:

```
SELECT total.source,COUNT(total.source) FROM (
SELECT *,"SOURCE1" AS source FROM INV1 WHERE ITEMID = 'TEST1'
UNION
SELECT *,"SOURCE2" AS source FROM INV2 WHERE ITEMID = 'TEST1'
UNION
SELECT *,"SOURCE3" AS source FROM INV3 WHERE ITEMID = 'TEST1'
) AS total 
GROUP BY total.source
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess around with subqueries or CTEs I would just create a view that does the UNION and then base the ORM object on that.

```py
from pprint import pprint

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    String,
    select,
    MetaData,
    Table,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    declarative_base,
    Session,
)

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

meta = MetaData()
inv1 = Table(
    "inv1",
    meta,
    Column("itemid", String(10)),
    Column("description", String(50)),
)
inv2 = Table(
    "inv2",
    meta,
    Column("itemid", String(10)),
    Column("description", String(50)),
)
meta.create_all(engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS item")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        """\
        CREATE VIEW item AS
        SELECT *,'SOURCE1' AS source FROM inv1
        UNION
        SELECT *,'SOURCE2' AS source FROM inv2
        """
    )

    # example data
    conn.execute(
        inv1.insert(), {"itemid": "TEST1", "description": "from inv1"}
    )
    conn.execute(
        inv2.insert(),
        [
            {"itemid": "TEST1", "description": "from inv2"},
            {"itemid": "TEST2", "description": "from inv2"},
        ],
    )

Base = declarative_base()


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item"  # based on UNION view ==> readonly
    itemid = Column(String(10), primary_key=True)
    source = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Item(id={repr(self.itemid)}, source={repr(self.source)}, description={repr(self.description)})>"


with Session(engine) as sess:
    result = sess.scalars(select(Item).where(Item.itemid == "TEST1")).all()
    pprint(result)
    """
    [(<Item(id='TEST1', source='SOURCE1', description='from inv1')>,),
     (<Item(id='TEST1', source='SOURCE2', description='from inv2')>,)]
    """
```

Comment: Thank you Gord for the help. but I have my own work around,

My original question still stand, as it is something that I believe should be extremely easy to do, without creating view, and so super duper fancy stuff.

The Union is definitely not the problem, adding the source column is :-(